# Clever way to prevent broken ssh-configs from making server inaccessible

Tags: backup, automation, sshd

So from time to time I make a change to a sshd-config file and break something, because I forget to test it with `sshd -t`. Fixing it often requires me to walk over and plug into the machine or in case of a headless Raspi, take it's SD card out and fix it on my PC. Which is tedious, to say the least.

What are good "best practice" ways to prevent this? I was thinking, maybe a backup script that runs every 10 minutes and replaces the ssh-config with a backup file if it is broken and iff the sshd-service is offline; or something like that. Is there a better and secure way to do this?

Comment: You could have two instances of `sshd` running, with the latter on a different port and rarely reconfigured.

Comment: That seems really interesting. How do I configure this, so it works on startup as well?

Comment: Depends on your system. If systemd is available you would probably want to write (or copy) a second `ssh.service` unit and have it invoke `sshd` with a different `sshd_config` file. I can give a more detailed answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to create a secondary `sshd` listening on a different port and using a different configuration file.

Firstly, create the unit file `/etc/systemd/system/ssh-backup.service` with contents

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server (Backup)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t -f /etc/ssh/sshd_backup_config
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS -f /etc/ssh/sshd_backup_config
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t -f /etc/ssh/sshd_backup_config
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd-backup.service
```

If you plan on modifying `/etc/default/ssh`, you may want to have the two daemons use different environment files.

Create a secondary sshd config at `/etc/ssh/sshd_backup_config` making sure to specify a port other than 22.

Once you're happy with the configuration file, call

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable --now ssh-backup.service
```

to reload and start the service.

Having the daemon running on a different port does not add any security at all. You will need to make sure the ssh daemon is at least as secure as the main one, if not more secure since it's going to be neglected.

Comment: This will solve my problem, thank you. Just one last thing, do you think it is a good idea to have a crontab running that checks if the main sshd is up and if not starts the secondary one? Instead of letting an unmaintained one run all the time.

Comment: I don't see an unmaintained one as being a security problem if you're disabling password authentication, PAM, etc, and have a seperate `AuthorizedKeysFile` with SSH keys you'll only use for this case. You could have a cron job but in the  case`sshd_config` is valid but causes you to be locked out, then the cron job wont fire up the secondary one since it will see the daemon as running.